# Failure of task on batch file in Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I created a batch file which would change the name of a specific file into the designated name. If I manually execute the .bat file, it will work fine, the name changes as expected. Yet the problem I met is the .bat file didn't work (the name wasn't changed) when it is scheduled in Task Scheduler. The log message in History, Task Category, all displays completed, but the .bat file just didn't change the name.

I've tried to search related articles that looks like a solution to me, yet so far, no luck. 
I've tried filling the quoted and unquoted paths in 'Program/script' and 'Start in (optional)' of the task, it still doesn't work.

e.g. pathname and "pathname"

Will a space in the path nullify the task when it is scheduled to run? Does anyone have any possible solution that can make my .bat file executed as scheduled?

The following is the content of the .bat file.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM The previous 6 SET statements are for extracting the specific time value.
SET year=%date:~-13,4%
SET "month=00%date:~-8,2%"
SET "month=%month:~2%"
SET "day=00%date:~-5,2%"
SET "day=%day:~-2%"
REM /a sets string to a numerical expression that is evaluated.
SET  /a "day-=1"
SET FileName=幹你妹_%year%%month%%day%.pdf
REN 幹你妹.pdf %FileName%
```

Comment: If it works when you run it manually, then I would say that the likely problem is that it's not being run in the right folder. But you said you filled in the "Start in" field. You could try to be explicit in the `REN` command by providing absolute paths, e.g. `ren C:\path\to\xyz.pdf C:\path\to\%filename%`. If that doesn't work, you might try echoing the variables to a log, e.g. `echo %date%>>C:\log.txt`.

Comment: As an aside, why are you going through the two-step process for day and month? Also, I think the quotes in your `SET` commands are more confusing than beneficial. Maybe that's just me?

Comment: @soja - while there are significantly better ways to split the date into its parts, the quotes are there to prevent accidental additional spaces.

Comment: @soja , I've solved the problem, I added quotation mark of the path in 'Program/script' and remain everything else.
And about your 2nd question, I gotta say I'm not familiar with batch command, it's just the quickest solution for some task of full automation.
You have any recommendation (better way) for the statements of batch command? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added quotation mark into the path on 'Program/script' and remain everything else to make it run successfully and as scheduled.